# "SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated" issue - Configured H2 DB to diagnose but column size change not taking effect?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, h2, truncation

**What?**

When investigating an `SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated` issue in a Java Spring Boot app, I configured H2 as an alternative to give me some better diagnostic error messages and more flexibility in recreating the scenario.

**TLDR?** 
Skip to *And the problem is...*

**How did you configure the Spring Boot application?**

I configured my Spring Boot application to use an H2 database instead of SQL Server as follows:

1. Exported the schema from SQL Server and created a script `db/sql/test.sql` to create the schema and objects in H2 - I've shrunk this to a single field for purposes of brevity.

   ```
   CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "MYSCHEMA";

   CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."MyTable"
   (
       MyField nvarchar(1500)
   )
   ```
2. Configured a maven dependency for H2:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
       <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.197</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Configured the datasource in application.yml to use H2:

   ```
   spring:
     datasource:
       database: HSQL
       driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
       url: jdbc:h2:mem:MyDBName
       username: sa
       password:
   ```
4. Created a test configuration class to define an injectable datasource bean to run the Schema creation `test.sql` script:

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class TestConfiguration {
       @Bean
       public DataSource dataSource() {
           EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
           EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
               .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
               .addScript("db/sql/test.sql")
               .setName("MyDBName")
               .build();
           return db;
       }
   }
   ```

**What happened when you ran the app using this configuration?**

Having configured this, I ran a test scenario and H2 immediately gave me the name of the field being truncated in its error message (thanks H2!) along with the data that would be truncated (and its length).

**Did increasing the field size prevent the error?**

The column in error was of size 1500. After resizing the size of the field in the script and in the Hibernate Entity class to 2000, the data truncation error no longer occurred for my test case.

**Did the truncation error still occur when you restored the column to the original size?**

When I changed the H2 schema creation script to resize the column to its original size (1500), the truncation error did not occur, despite the data being > 1500 in size.

**And the problem is...?**

Why did my change in column size in `test.sql` not have any effect?

Answer (score 1):

**What's going on?**

The tables were being created by hibernate automatically, based on definitions in the Entity classes themselves, with the contents of the creation script being *partially* ignored.

**What did Entity column length look like?**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable", schema="mySchema")
public class myEntity {
    @Column(length=2000) private String myField;
}
```

**Which bits of the script were needed?**

The only part of the `db/sql/test.sql` script required was to create the schema.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "MYSCHEMA";
```

**What about the tables and columns?**

All tables, columns and column sizes were then auto-generated from the `@Entity` classes.

**Anything else to be aware of?**

Yes, it also useful to know that all `String` types in the Entity default to an implementation of `varchar(255)` so for any field that is longer than this, you will need to specify an `@Column(size=...)` annotation.

**TL;DR?**

The column length in the created database was coming from my `@Column` annotation and not from the .sql script's `CREATE TABLE` statement!

**Addendum**

With H2 now configured, I could then easily switch between using SQL Server or using H2 to diagnose issues when replaying a testcase.

**Thanks H2!**

H2's error messages told me exactly what data was going to be truncated and which  column was affected, and what the length of the actual data was. With the column and data identified, I was able to dig into the code to figure out where it was coming from.

Comment: "which column": At first i thought it is due to a security concern. But seems like it has been "fixed" in SQL Server 2016 CP2+: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32909539-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated

Comment: @vulcanraven Thanks, that's useful! An example of updated message format Microsoft gives is: 
`String or binary data would be truncated in table 'AdventureWorks2016CTP3.Sales.SalesOrderHeaderTest', column 'CreditCardApprovalCode'. Truncated value: '1231736Vi8604'.`
which is certainly a lot more helpful than the original!

Answer (score -1):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
public class Table implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "MyField", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String myField;
}
```

Comment: please explain how your code fixes the original problem.

Comment: The column size defined in the entity takes precedence over any column sizes specified in the sql script. So in this case, the size of the database column is dictated by the `length` value specified inside the `@Column()` annotation.
So if, in the code you pasted, you wanted a column size of 300, the `@Column` line would need to read:
`@Column(name = "MyField", columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 300)`

i.e. you need to add a `length=xxx` value inside the @Column attribute.